# Force subtitles to play as default

Tags: quicktime, subtitles

I've added different language subtitles to individual m4v movies, and they show fine when selecting the subtitle track in both Quicktime and VLC. I would like to have them so that the subtitles display by default. Any way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [MP4Box 0.6.2-DEV-rev453](//gpac.wp.mines-telecom.fr/downloads/gpac-nightly-builds) (May 2016) or higher to do this:

```
mp4box -add alfa.mp4 -add bravo.srt:txtflags=0xC0000000 -new charlie.mp4
```

[Example](//github.com/svnpenn/a/blob/af30667/etc/mp4box.sh#L27-L28)

This will mark the subtitle stream in the output file as forced.

**However**, this mark will only be recognized starting with these versions of
programs:

- [MPC-HC 1.7.10.207](//nightly.mpc-hc.org) (May 2016)
- [VLC media player 3.0.0-20161101](//nightlies.videolan.org) (Nov 2016)

---

I have seen mentions to [this post](//ffmpeg.org/pipermail/ffmpeg-devel/2015-January/167371.html) on the FFmpeg mailing list about a
patch that implements disposition for FFmpeg:

```
ffmpeg -i alfa.mp4 -i bravo.srt -c copy -c:s mov_text -disposition:s forced charlie.mp4
```

However after having tried it with both "forced" and "default", the subtitles
marked by FFmpeg are not recognized as forced by either MPC-HC or VLC.

Answer (score 1):

Afaik apart from Blu-ray's and DVD's only MKV supports forced subtitles.
If you want the subtitles to be "burned" into the video. Meaning they are part of the pixel frames you can use a tool like ffmpeg. A nice tutorial specific to mp4/m4v can be found here: http://forum.videohelp.com/threads/277706-How-to-add-subtitles-permanently-to-existing-mp4-h-264-file?p=2305682&viewfull=1#post2305682

MP4 definitely can not show forced subtitles in software. There might be another format other than MKV that supports forced subtitles that I don't know of but mp4 definitely doesn't have that in its specs.